# Spring Security: Unable to have both authenticated and non authenticated Endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm facing what I think is an ordering issue of my extended WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter which I would be very grateful if someone could take a look / offer some advice.

To give some context. I'm working on a API which has a fair amount of endpoints. Up until this point all endpoints where secured behind a JWT / Authentication object like so:

```
 @GetMapping("/me")
    public User getLoggedInUsersProfile(@ApiIgnore Authentication authentication,
                                        @RequestParam(value = "profileView", required = false) String profileView) {
        logger.info("Request received from User with Id {} to retrieve their profile", authentication.getName());
        return userService.getUserProfileFromDB(authentication.getName());
    }
```

However now I need to have a single endpoint which can be accessed by anyone without a JWT.
I tried adding a antMatcher and permit all for said endpoint BUT it giving me a 401. Now I did manage to get it somewhat working however then the endpoint in the code snippet above would throw a 500 if a JWT was omitted from the request (due to it authentication being null). I don't really want to add a null check for each of the endpoints as there are a LOT.

Here is my security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = false)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${auth0.audience}")
    private String audience;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuer;

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3010"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("Authorization");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .headers().referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.SAME_ORIGIN)
                .and()
                .xssProtection()
                .and()
                .contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self'").and()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .formLogin()
                .disable()
                .httpBasic()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .anonymous().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/admin/**").permitAll().and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/health", "/health/**");
    }

        @Bean
        JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
            /*
            By default, Spring Security does not validate the "aud" claim of the token, to ensure that this token is
            indeed intended for our app. Adding our own validator is easy to do:
            */

            NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder)
                    JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);

            OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(audience);
            OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
            OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);

            jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);

            return jwtDecoder;
        }

        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
            JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter converter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
            converter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("permissions");
            converter.setAuthorityPrefix("");

            JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
            jwtConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(converter);
            return jwtConverter;
        }
}
```

Can anyone please give me some advice / spot whats wrong.

Many thanks in advance

** EDIT **

I currently handle when a user does not supply a JWT with this class:

```
@Component
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Value("${error.unauthorized}")
    private String unauthorizedErrorCode;

    @Value("${api.version}")
    private String currentApiVersion;


    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);
    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);
    // This is invoked when user tries to access a secured REST resource without supplying any credentials
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                         HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                         AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.error("Responding with unauthorized error. Message - {}", e.getMessage());

        final AppError error = new AppError(
                currentApiVersion,
                unauthorizedErrorCode,
                "Access Denied",
                httpServletRequest.getRequestURI(),
                "Invalid or Missing Token",
                e.getMessage(),
                "https://xxxxxx.ai/sendreport?"
        );

        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/json");

        MDC.put("api.version", httpServletRequest.getContextPath());
        MDC.put("Server.IP", httpServletRequest.getServerName());
        MDC.put("API.Controller", httpServletRequest.getServletPath());
        MDC.put("Response.code", String.valueOf(httpServletResponse.getStatus()));
        MDC.put("Request.Method.Type", httpServletRequest.getMethod());

        LOGGER.info("statusCode {}, path: {}, method: {}, query {}, context {}, serverName {}, RequestURI {}, RemoteHost {}, Cookies {}",
                httpServletResponse.getStatus(), httpServletRequest.getRequestURI(), httpServletRequest.getMethod(),
                httpServletRequest.getQueryString(), httpServletRequest.getContextPath(),
                httpServletRequest.getServerName(), httpServletRequest.getRequestURI(), httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr(),
                httpServletRequest.getCookies());
        MDC.clear();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(httpServletResponse.getOutputStream(), error);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are asking Spring Context to inject the Authentication in your getLoggedInUsersProfile method's parameters. When the user is not logged in, the authentication is null. You are then using authentication.getName(): when the authentication is null, this will lead to null pointer exception. I think you need to decide what your endpoint should do when the user is not logged in, and modify your logic accordly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This makes sense However I handle the non logged in user via the RestAuthenticationEntryPoint class which should fire a 401 whenever a JWT is not present in the header.

Comment: Is there anyway I can keep this functionality but allow just one endpoint to unauthenticated?

Comment: It's not that you can't allow both the endpoints. The problem is that your code will lead to a NullPointerException on the /me endpoint when the user is not logged in. You need to change that code, first

Comment: Thanks for that. Sigh thats not what I was hoping for :-D I wanted a nice easy day today :D Thanks for the help truly appreciated. So if I do that then I think I can just get rid of the RestAuthenticationEntryPoint class right?

Comment: Actually, is there a way that i can avoid having to check for a null on every endpoint. Seems rather redundant

Comment: i dont understand what your question is, you are wondering why the `/me` endpoint throws a nullpointer? why not have that endpoint return a 401 when someone doesnt supply a jwt?

Comment: Hi Toerktumlare! Thanks for the response. Nope I get why it throws a null pointer. The class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint is fired when a token is not sent with the request. However